# scripting Audacity

Tags: windows, scripting, audacity

Is there any scripting library for Audacity?

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to give it a long mp3 file `podcast.mp3` and have it split into files of, say, 10 minutes each: `podcast0.mp3, podcast1.mp3` etc...

I don't want to do this manually, since I want to run all the podcasts I listen to through this script.

---

**Some background:**
There are various podcasts I listen to (for instance, Stackoverflow) that are very long.  I listen to these on my cellphone which has a dinky MP3 player that doesn't allow me to jump to an arbitrary time in the file.  This MP3 player has a nasty habit of forgetting where in the file I was.  For instance:

- Sometimes if somebody calls me while I'm in the middle of a podcast it'll start it from the beginning.
- Sometimes I pause a podcast when I get to work, and when I try to continue it at the end of the day it's reset to the beginning of the track.

When this happens, I have to manually fast forward it or rewind it.  This dinky player fast-forwards at a rate of 5x, so if I was in the middle of the podcast it can take me 6 or 7 minutes of holding the fast-forward button to get back to where I was.  I figure if I split the long podcasts into shorter files, I can save a bit of annoyance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a different tool such as [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [mp3split](http://sourceforge.net/docman/display_doc.php?docid=12439&group_id=55130). Those are command-line tools so will be easy to script.

Comment: you could also use sox

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in splitting the files, then I would go with Douglas' suggestions.
However, if you want to use Audacity for its GUI capabilities, Audacity has scripting capability that uses the pipe.  It's called mod-script-pipe.  If you download the source from svn you will see an example in the scripts folder named pipe-test.pl.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac (happy user you are! :-)), you can use [Automator](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2488) to do such a thing.